# log4j in my servlet is logging to the tomcat root

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, log4j, apache-axis

I am writing a servlet that will run in Tomcat (or other container) and wish to use Log4J to do logging from my servlet. However, **my RollingFileAppender is logging to the Tomcat root** rather than the webapp root. So `Tomcat_dir/mylog.log` rather than `Tomcat_dir/webapps/MyServlet/mylog.log`

Here is my properties file (which I can tell is being loaded because it properly sets the log file name):

```
#logfile is an appender (references log4j.appender.logfile)
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console, logfile
# Logging levels from most logging to least: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL

# Setup for console logging
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p](%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}) (%F:%L) - %m%n

#setup for logging to files
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=mylog.log
log4j.appender.logfile.Append=true
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.logfile.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p](%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS})(%F:%L) - %m%n
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple, although most of the examples I've seen use an absolute path or the servlet context (which I don't have in my part of the code).

Edit: Also it may be relevant that my servlet is a service that was generated from a WSDL using Axis2

Answer (score 1):

Use the `${catalina.base}` var as described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j)

```
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.file=${catalina.base}/logs/localhost.
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.conversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.append=true
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It just ignores the ${catalina.base} part of file path. This may be because my servlet is something I actually generated using Axis from a WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that this config file is loaded and used by your application? Maybe your servlet uses tomcats config file.

To double check, add a significant change to your conversion pattern and verify, that your messages are logged using that pattern.

Comment: Yes, I've added the string JAX to my conversion pattern and I get logs like this now:
    `[INFO](05 May 2011 09:27:30,730)(?:?) JAX - ---Logger initialized---`